# Presentations.Open Method failed for MS PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I am calling VBA code from an Excel spreadsheet to open an existing PowerPoint file via the `Presentations.Open` method. In my environment I developed via Early Binding using the MS PowerPoint 14.0  Object Library and the codes run without a problem.

However, when the script was called in another machine that runs MS Office 2013 (i.e. MS PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library), a Run-time error pops up

> Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed

Is the Presentations.Open method deprecated in PPT 15.0 Object library? I tried searching Internet but couldn't find documentation on the change.

I also attempted to use Late Binding to see if it works, but received the same error.

Please find below the code snipnets I used (early + late binding).

Thank you very much for the help.

---

*Early Binding Code Snipnet*

```
Sub EarlyBinding()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim PowerpointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set PowerpointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
PowerpointApp.Visible = True

Dim myPath As String
myPath = ws.Range("wk_dir").Value & "\" & ws.Range("ppt_name").Value

Set myPresentation = PowerpointApp.presentations.Open(myPath)
myPresentation.SaveAs (ws.Range("wk_dir").Value & "\test_earlybind.pptx")

Set myPresentation = Nothing
Set PowerpointApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

*Late Binding Code Snipnet*

```
Sub LateBinding()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim PowerpointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object

Set PowerpointApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
PowerpointApp.Visible = True

Dim myPath As String
myPath = ws.Range("wk_dir").Value & "\" & ws.Range("ppt_name").Value

Set myPresentation = PowerpointApp.presentations.Open(myPath)

myPresentation.SaveAs (ws.Range("wk_dir").Value & "\test_latebind.pptx")

Set myPresentation = Nothing
Set PowerpointApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct for the other machine?

Comment: `debug.print myPath` and what comes up?

Comment: A) Presentations.Open is supported in pretty much any version of Windows PowerPoint back to Office 97 and on any Mac version that includes VBA.  B) You'd get a "Method or Data Member not found" error message if you called an unsupported method. As the others have suggested, verify that the file you're trying to open actually exists.

Comment: Does this happen for any given file? Or is it perhaps that you locked it somehow?

Comment: Tried Debug.Print before, it is indeed a valid path.
If a file is simply not found, there is a run-time error "PowerPoint could not open the file". Not the case here though

Answer (score 0):

`presentations.Open()` may fail if you pass a relative path as parameter. The reason is that *PowerPoint* uses its own working directory which is usually different from the working directory of the calling application.

The solution is to pass an absolute path rather than a relative one.